# Simple AJAX Script will NOT load on Homepage only

Tags: javascript, ajax, browser-security

My email script on the left navigation panel... under "Brad's Secrets of Attraction" will not load on the homepage. It works on EVERY other page.

Live Site: [BradP.com](http://www.BradP.com) **SITE MAY BE NSFW**

This is strange to me.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: I love that someone marked this offensive :)  A little T&A never killed nobody.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script seems to load (activate actually) only when you **first** visit the page.  In other words, when I refreshed it didn't load, but it did once I had cleared my cookies.  Therefore it seems to be triggered on some sort of cookie.  Does this help?

Answer (score 2):

FireBug reports:

uncaught exception: Access to restricted URI denied (NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI)
[Break on this error] eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,r){e=function(c)...h|borderTopWidth|abbr'.split('|'),0,{}))

It works on bradp.com but not www.bradp.com probably because your base href is bradp.com. Try removing the base href and see if that fixes it.

Comment: To add to the posters answer, this is a cross-site scripting security measure within the browser.